# Можно ли выполнить sql запрос под условием

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте допустим у меня есть таблица которая хранит товары и есть таблица со складами. каждый товар может находится либо только на одном складе либо вообще не находится на складе. Если товар находится на складе то в таблице товаров по этому товару записывается идентификатор склада
Вот пример таблиц
[![простая схема таблиц][1]][1]

если я делаю запрос SELECT * FROM storoge, product WHERE storoge.id = product.storoge_id то у меня в выборку попадают товары только если они есть на складе а надо что бы все попадали. Скорее всего я туплю, но прошу помочь)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1WBJ.png

Comment: LEFT JOIN в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного смущает в заголовке "под условием".
Если я вас правильно понял, то вот пример запроса:

```
SELECT product.*, storage.name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN storage ON product.storage_id = storage.id
```

Можете [почитать](https://function-x.ru/sql_join.html) краткую информацию по JOIN-ам и [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/)

Дополнения:
Если в игру вступает 3-я таблица (address) и никакой структуры о ней я не знаю ), буду наугад представлять ее.

```
SELECT product.*, storage.name, address.name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN storage ON product.storage_id = storage.id
LEFT JOIN address ON storage.address_id = address.id
```

Comment: да именно это было и нужно спасибо огромное, но не подскажите в этом же запросе, мне надо получить адрес склада т.е. связать ещё storage с adress, что то типа  storage.adrees_id = adress.id
Получается что у нас в одном запросе не всё к одной таблице привязывается

Comment: Правильно ли вы пытаетесь организовать структуру таблиц, если у вас таблица storage отвечает за физическое нахождение товара на складе, а таблица adress за список адресов? И судя по всему связь там будет многие к одному.  Правильно ли это?
Если в данном случае таблица storage рассматривается как самодостаточная сущность, описывающая склад, то может в ней сразу хранить адрес склада и не делать лишний JOIN между таблицами storage <-> address? В чем смысл разделения адреса от склада по разные таблицы?

Comment: Такая структура базы была спроектирована изначально, и адреса были вынесены в отдельную таблицу так как по одному адресу могут находится не только склад но и другие сущности и как я понял для этого адреса были вынесены в отдельную таблицу. Но с такой структурой у меня возникает сложность связки таблиц в запросе если использовать  LEFT JOIN

Comment: Понял ) скажите, второй запрос, помог вам?

Comment: Евгений я сейчас на природе. Завтра протестирую и отпишусь. Спасибо вам огромное)